# Why is this Roman bust identified as Arminius?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire, art

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arminius#Rome) and [Britannica](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:d0YyQdEF8ooJ:https://www.britannica.com/biography/Arminius+&cd=2&hl=es&ct=clnk&gl=us) show this bust in their articles about Arminius:

[image: Bust of Arminius, according to Britannica.com]

The caption in Wikipedia says:

> This Roman sculpture of a young man is sometimes identified as
>   Arminius.

The description in [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arminius_pushkin.jpg) is this:

> German, so called Arminius. Cast in Pushkin museum after original in
>   Dresden

<s>Besides being found in Dresden (I guess),</s> What reasons have led some historians to identify this as Arminius?

Doesn't look much barbarian to me (what, no moustache?)

Comment: Note that Arminius was not a "barbarian" by any meaning of the word. He was a Roman citizen, equestrian, spoke fluent latin, and served as military commander in the Roman army.

Comment: You're right, @DevSolar. I thought of that only after posting my question :/. The answer provided is still excellent though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The earliest reference I've found to this bust is from 1854, in the section 'Supposed Bust of Arminus' of [The Ruins and Museums of Rome: A Guide Book for Travellers, Artists, and Lovers of Antiquity](https://books.google.com/books?id=4mgoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=bust%20of%20arminius&source=bl&ots=O8k6lMVhZc&sig=tpGAhUJtn_EMVTo89R9rJGFrn-0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_qdmKk4PQAhXI7SYKHW9uA2UQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Emil Braun.

The author states that apperently this bust was earlier identified with [Cecrops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecrops_I), but

> The supposition of a professional archaeologist which reached me
>   indirectly, that this bust may represent the hero of the Teutonic
>   civil war struck me as a highly suggestive idea.

The author agrees that

> The abundant hair the incipient down on the chin the rather massive
>   cheekbones announce the son of the North.

The article also states that the bust was originally found near Naples, and
the [Britanica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Arminius/images-videos/Arminius-bust-in-the-Capitoline-Museum-Rome/8550) article lists it as in the Capitoline Museum, so I don't find  any significance to the Dresden reference, unless that is its current location.

The consensus seems to be that the hair is too un-Roman like, and in fact, if you look closely, the trace of that 'barbarian' mustache is visible over the lip. Some more recent works such as [Four Days in September: The Battle of Teutoburg](https://books.google.com/books?id=bNwHDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT62&dq=bust%20of%20arminius&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMkq-7moPQAhVQ3yYKHTF9BrIQ6AEIRzAH#v=onepage&q=bust%20of%20arminius&f=false) by Jason R. Abdale discuss that this may have been a more generic image of the 'Germanic Barbarian' type.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the great answer, @user2448131. I'll wait a bit before accepting it, for now I eliminated the Dresden comment.